# Proof of NP-completeness of the 3-SAT problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra, np-complete

> **Proposition :** The 3-satisfiability problem 3-SAT is NP-complete.
>
> **Proof :** We give a polynomial-time reduction of SAT to 3-SAT. Let $f(x_1, x_2,\ldots)$ be a Boolean expression. Introduce a variable $y_g$
> for each subword $g$ of $f$ that is a Boolean expression (not
> splitting variables). Now $f$ is satisfiable if and only if the
> following system is satisfiable:
>
> $y_g = y_{g′} \lor y_{g′′}$ (if $g = (g′ ∨ g′′))$,
>
> $y_g = y_{g′} \land y_{g′′}$ (if $g = (g′ ∧ g′′))$,
>
> $y_g = \neg y_{g′}$ (if $g = \neg g′)$,
>
> $y_f = 1$.
>
> Now $y_g = y_{g′}\lor y_{g′′}$ can be
> equivalently expressed by: $y_g\lor\neg y_{g′} = 1$, $y_g\lor \neg
> y_{g′′} =1$, $\neg y_g \lor y_{g′} \lor y_{g′′} = 1$. Similarly, $y_g
> = y_{g′} \land y_{g′′}$ can be equivalently expressed by: $\neg y_g\lor y_{g′} = 1$, $\neg y_g\lor y_{g′′} = 1$, $y_g\lor\neg
> y_{g′}\lor\neg y_{g′′} = 1$. The expression $y_g = \neg y_{g′}$ is
> equivalent to: $y_g \lor y_{g′} = 1,\neg y_g \lor\neg y_{g′} = 1$. By
> renaming variables, we thus obtain words $w_1,\ldots, w_k$ in $B_2$,
> such that $f$ is satisfiable if and only if the word $w_1 \land\ldots
> \land w_k$ is satisfiable.

What does "not splitting variables" mean? Also I don't get the last part

> By renaming variables, we thus obtain words $w_1,\ldots, w_k$ in
> $B_2$, such that $f$ is satisfiable if and only if the word $w_1
> \land\ldots \land w_k$ is satisfiable.

It would be useful to see the proof worked on an example to understand what is going on.

Comment: I think in the second displayed equation it should be $\land$ instead of $\lor$? And there seem to be several extraneous $>$ signs in some of the inline equations.

Comment: @joriki, thank you for the comment, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence means that by renaming the variables, we can obtain a set of clauses $w_1, w_2, ..., w_k$ in a format such that each clause consists of exactly two literals (i.e., a variable or its negation), and the expression $f$ is satisfiable if and only if the conjunction (i.e., logical "and") of all these clauses $w_1 \land w_2 \land ... \land w_k$ is satisfiable. This means that the original SAT problem has been transformed into an equivalent 3-SAT problem, which can then be solved efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide an example to illustrate?